# GITkit "Account Chooser" Questions

Tags: authentication, openid

Has anyone successfully implemented the ***Google Identity Toolkit***, an implementation of an [***Account Chooser***](http://accountchooser.com/). I followed the initial steps here, but I still have a few questions, as I don't quite know how to handle the entire data flow. I'm using Clojure / Compojure in the back-end:

- http://havethunk.wordpress.com/2011/08/10/google-identity-toolkit-asp-net-mvc3/
- http://code.google.com/apis/identitytoolkit/v1/acguide.html

A) don't quite understand how ID Provider authentication, fits into my data model

- when implementing the callbackURL, what data should I expect, and
  how's that session state managed by GITkit (and all Account Choosers)

B) Is there a way to set this up the 'callbackURL' for development.

- the identity provider would need a URL that it can redirect back to

C) How can the GITkit / Account Chooser workflow let my users register an account that's native to my app?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone's future reference. I was able to resolve the issue. You can follow [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/google-identity-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/da6442b60fec7117/8d16622a71668ec6?show_docid=8d16622a71668ec6) of how's it's done in Clojure.

I got it working with Ring/Compojure, and another fellow showed me his solution in Webnoir.

HTH

Answer (score 2):

The questions aren't entirely clear, but I've done an implementation of [GITkit in ruby](http://code.google.com/p/gitkit-ruby) and can give you some pointers.

A) The callback URL is what handles the assertion from the identity providers.  Rightnow GITKit only does OpenID, so the URL will contain an OpenID response either in the query parameters or as the POST body.  You'll need to do a few things:
  1) Call verifyAssertion in the gitkit API and pass the params/post body.  This will return a JSON response that contains the user details (assuming assertion is valid).  There are some other checks you should do as well 
  2) Decide what to do with the assertion.  If it is an existing user, most likely you'll just establish a session and save the user ID.  If it's a new user, you can either create a new account and start a session immediately, or defer that and redirect them to a signup page.
  3) Render HTML/JS to notify the widget.  There are different status codes and data you can return that changes the flow.

GITKit itself doesn't really manage session state, that's up to your app.  Some of the reference implementations have code to help, but it's not part of the API.  The widget does have some state that you can control with JS (add account, show as logged in, etc) and uses local storage in the browser.

The [docs](http://code.google.com/apis/identitytoolkit/v1/acguide.html#details) give some details and example code for how this should be implemented.

B) Of course.  The URL is just configured in the javascript widget when you call setConfig()  It can be set to localhost or any staging server for development.  So long as your browser can reach it you're OK.

C) By "native", I assume you mean where they're signing up with just a username/password instead of using an IDP.  If so, the user just has to enter their email address when logging in.  If that email address matches a known IDP it'll attempt to authenticate with OpenID, otherwise if it's a new user it'll redirect to whatever signup page you configured in the widget.  That signup page would just ask the user to create a password like you normally would.  You should also return whether or not accounts are 'legacy' (password) accounts in the userStatus checks.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help on this. It definitely pointed me in the right direction. My big dilemma though, was getting past the 'verifyAssertion' call. I kept getting an HTTP 503 error (meaning service is temp. unavail), when Google's API should have been giving me more detailed error messages (it wanted a particular format to the 'requestUri'). Cheers.

Comment: There's one last thing I'm wondering about. 

I've gotten past the verifyAssertion call, and I need to return that value back to the gitkit component. The trick is, I need to take that returned JSON, and use it as a parameter in a call to 'notifyFederatedSuccess' ( [see here](http://code.google.com/apis/identitytoolkit/v1/acguide.html#details) ). 

Due to Gitkit's workflow, we redirect to a result page after a successful callBackUrl / verifyAssertion trip. So how do you pass a JSON to that page via a redirect, then get that inserted JSON in  your call. Continued...

Comment: Additionally, the POST call workflow originates from the gitkit popup page. If it were my page making the call, I could handle the redirect directive. Even with a JSONP call, the response gets returned to the calling client. Again, in this case, another page (gitkit popup) kicks off the workflow. And on success, I have to redirect to my page, which takes the result JSON and calls  _window.google.identitytoolkit.notifyFederatedSuccess( resultUser )_.

So again, the real question is, **how do I send JSON to a page that I'm rendering for the first time?**

Comment: The response from the callback URL (which is where you're calling verifyAssertion) should be an HTML page that you render using whatever mechanism you use for any of your server side HTML generation.  The contents of the page are the script to call notifyFederatedSuccess (or failure) along with the results.  That call will take care of the cross-frame communication to alert the main page that auth is done and close the popup.  See step 3 in the guide where it says "returning the response code".

Comment: Generating HTML, instead of serving it up static, is a fair approach. Thanks.